# IIS reverse proxy with owncloud and keycloak backend

Tags: iis, keycloak, identityserver4, owncloud

## What I'm trying to achieve

I would like to create an IIS reverse proxy with hostname `http://innerhub.domain.example/` and I would like to configure it to split the traffic as follows:

- `http://innerhub.domain.example/owncloud` goes to `http://192.168.0.192:8080/` as my owncloud service is hosting on that ip:port.
- `http://innerhub.domain.example/keyclkauth` goes to `http://192.168.0.192:8180/` as my keycloak service is hosting on that ip:port

## Why I'm doing this

As owncloud documentation describes Owncloud's openID connect needs a reverse proxy so your IAPs can access the configuration under .well-known. So I figured I need to setup a reverse proxy between the owncloud and the keycloak in order to rewrite the .well-known url. It would work fine, but in order so owncloud redirects me to the correct url too I need to be able to access keycloak url too from the innerhub. So basically innerhub needs to split and rewrite urls between these two sites.
[This is the network graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRU48.png)

## What works so far

The url rewrite rules are working and I can reach the apps with `http://innerhub.domain.example/*`

## Where am I stuck

Owncloud and keycloak too has response.redirect messages and I can't find a way to properly handle this in IIS. When owncloud redirects I get a new url: `http://innerhub.domain.example/login` and obviously it returns a 404, because this should be `http://innerhub.domain.example/owncloud/login`

## My configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="KeyCloak" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^/?keyclkauth/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.192:8180/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SCHEMA" value="http" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="http" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
                <rule name="OwnCloudAuth" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^/?owncloud/\.well-known/openid-configuration" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.192:8080/index.php/apps/openidconnect/config" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="OwnCloud" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^/?owncloud/?(.*)" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SCHEMA" value="http" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="http" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.0.192:8080/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SCHEMA" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" />
                <add name="From_where" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="KeyCloak" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Link" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.0.192:8180/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http://innerhub.domain.example/keyclkauth/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="OwnCloudAuth" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Link" pattern="http://192.168.0.192:8080/index.php/apps/openidconnect/config" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http://innerhub.domain.example/owncloud/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="OwnCloud" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Link" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.0.192:8080/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http://innerhub.domain.example/owncloud/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="isStatus">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3[0-9][0-9]" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="x-forwarded-KeyCloak">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST}" pattern="http://innerhub.domain.example/keyclkauth/.*" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="x-forwarded-OwnCloud">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST}" pattern="http://innerhub.domain.example/owncloud/.*" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As far as I known, IIS doesn't have setting to rewrite responsed url from server to client. Have you tried to add another rule to rewrite url `/login` to `owncloud/login`? Or why not set in code response.redirect? I don't know owncloud, but ASP.NET add specific character in method Response.redirect("owncloud/login");

Comment: I can't edit Owncloud's code as far as I know so editing response.redirect is not an option.
In regards of /login to /owncloud/login. I can't assume that other backend application won't need that /login url path. I would somehow check the source of the response.redirect and with that I could determine which application sent the redirect. How would I do that?